# Get Location from Parse Facebook API

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, ipad, parse-platform

I am developing iPhone app in which i am doing sign in with facebook using Parse API

while doing sign in with facebook, i am getting lots of information of logged in user (Given below) from which i want to fetch location of user.

```
userdata ={
    birthday = "05/21/1987";
    education =     (
                {
            school =             {
                id = 120844281263915;
                name = Gurukul;
            };
            type = "High School";
            year =             {
                id = 143018465715205;
                name = 2000;
            };
        },
                {
            school =             {
                id = 518699864812774;
                name = VJTI;
            };
            type = College;
        }
    );
    email = "sunilvliya@gmail.com";
    "first_name" = Sunil;
    gender = male;
    hometown =     {
        id = 108867759137051;
        name = Jamnagar;
    };
    id = 100002439055169;
    "last_name" = Vadoliya;
    link = "https://www.facebook.com/sunil.vya.9";
    locale = "en_US";
    location =     {
        id = 108867759137051;
        name = Jamnagar;
    };
    name = "Sunil Valiya";
    timezone = "5.5";
    "updated_time" = "2012-07-18T13:58:11+0000";
    username = "sunil.vliya.9";
    verified = 1;
}
```

I want to get location name from above data, how can i get it ?

**Please help and thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a second request to the Facebook API to get the information about the location. The data from the user you provided includes both location and hometown. In order to get the information from the user's current city you'd make a request like this.

```
   NSString *locationId = [[theDictionaryWithUserData objectForKey:@"location"] objectForKey:@"id"];
    FBRequest *requesetForCity = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:locationId];
    [requesetForCity startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error){

     NSLog(@"%@", result);

     NSString *locationName = [result objectForKey:@"name"];

     }];
```

Comment: still i am not getting dude :(